# Send some data into script.py and recieve another data for placing it into html

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, flask

I'm making a web app in the flask. I can't properly carry out my idea.
In this case I want to receive some data from forms on the HTML page and send it to another script.py file. Then this script.py shall do some maths and return me and a couple of string variables. I want to receive them like a result of maths and put them separately on the HTML page ( like {{ var1 }} ).

Hhere is some code so that you roughly understand what the situation looks like now:

routes.py:

```
import some script as spst

...

@app.route('/calculate')
def calc_func():
    data1 = request.form['form1input']   # timepicker input like 07:30
    data2 = request.form['form2input']   # string 'hello'
    data3 = request.form['form3input']   # int 55
    fdata = data1[0:2]                   # 07
    fdata = data1[3:5]                   # 30
    fdata = data2                        # 'hello'
    fdata = data3                        # 55
    spst.mainclass.mainfunc(fdata1, fdata2, fdata3, fdata4)
    # how to catch results from function above???
    return render_template('index.html', output_text1, output_text2, output_text3)
```

somescript.py:

```
class mainclass(object):
    def mainfunc(fdata1, fdata2, fdata3, fdata4):
        localvar1 = int(fdata1)
        localvar2 = int(fdata2)
        localvar3 = str(fdata3)
        localvar4 = int(fdata4)
        # there is some maths and other actions
        output_text1 = str(result1)
        output_text2 = str(result2)
        output_text3 = str(result3)
        return output_text1, output_text2, output_text3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to set yout parameters correctly since there is nothing defined as fdata1, fdata2, fdata3 passed in your function and after that you can return a dictionary in your somescripyt.py file like this :

```
return {'output_var1': output_text1, 'output_var2': output_text2, 
        'output_var3': output_text3}
```

And then in your `calc_func()` in routes.py file just pass the returned result like this :

```
def calc_func():
    data1 = request.form['form1input']   # timepicker input like 07:30
    data2 = request.form['form2input']   # string 'hello'
    data3 = request.form['form3input']   # int 55
    fdata = data1[0:2]                   # 07
    fdata = data1[3:5]                   # 30
    fdata = data2                        # 'hello'
    fdata = data3                        # 55

    result = spst.mainclass.mainfunc(fdata1, fdata2, fdata3, fdata4)
    return render_template('index.html', result=result)
```

And then in your index.html you can use it in Jinja like below :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    {% if result %}
        {% for obj in result.keys() %}
            {{ result[obj] }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must assign the return value of your function to variables like this:

```
(output_text1, output_text2, output_text3) = spst.mainclass.mainfunc(fdata1, fdata2, fdata3, fdata4)
# how to catch results from function above???
return render_template('index.html', output_text1, output_text2, output_text3)
```

Right? Because those names in mainclass / mainfunc won't get carried out of the function call. The function returns 3 values, which you must assign to something to be able to use them.